# how to use a variable in form action to send an email

Tags: jquery, html

i have stored email_id from first form using jQuery.But how can i use it second form's `action:mailto:`?

```
<form id="sForm" action="mailto:abc@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <label for="name">Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" style="width: 100%;"><br>
    <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" style="width: 100%;"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" >
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
 </form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#sForm').on('submit',function(){ 
        var email_var = document.getElementById('email').value;
    });
});
</script>

<form id="pForm" action="mailto:???" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    ....
</form>
```

Comment: `action` and `method` attributes are used to set Url and request type.
although adding `mailto` on submit will open a new window which automatically populate the email fields but that doesn't trigger email, to actually trigger an email post to your server page that does the emailing on form submit

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#sForm').on('submit',function(){ 
      document.getElementById('pForm').action = 'mailto:'+document.getElementById('email').value;
    });
});
```

Instead of storing the email in an unused variable, change the action of the form to the right mailto:

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use some function in the "action" of the second form. example;

```
<script>

  var email = 'mailto:';

  $(document).ready(function(e){
      $('#sForm').on('submit',function(){ 
          email += document.getElementById('email').value;
      });
  });

  function getMail(){
     return email;
  }

</script>

<form id="pForm" action="javascript:getMail()" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```